# how to create kotlin infix function with 2 words?

Tags: unix

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 var arr = IntArray(10)
 println(arr get size) // prints size of arr
 arr print all //prints all elements of arr
```

I think "get size" is 2 infix function, get and size, and get function takes argument of size function result, and prints take argument of "all" function result, any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  Is this to be part of a new domain-specific language (in which case there are plenty of DSL-specific techniques you can read up on)?  Or because you like the look of it in normal Kotlin code (which case it's likely to confuse the hell out of anyone else you reads your code)?  Or is your interest purely theoretical?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve doesn't make much sense and you shouldn't implement such things in production. Just for educational propose, something similar can be achieved:

```
infix fun <T> Array<T>.get(parameter: String): Int {
    when(parameter) {
        "size" -> return this.size
    }
    throw NotImplementedError()
}
```

and usage would be:

```
println(array get "size")
```

Edit:
The version where you would call `array get size` will look the following:

```
enum class GetType { size }

infix fun <T> Array<T>.get(parameter: GetType): Int {
    when(parameter) {
        GetType.size -> return this.size
  }
```

However if you want to call `size` instead of `GetType.size` then you need to import everything in the enum class:

```
import GetType.*
```

Comment: alternatively use an enum as parameter... `enum class Getter { size }`... then it looks as requested: `arr get size`... (and also just for educational purposes ;-))

Comment: yes you can, however you will also need to import the class